# Sitecore Experience Analytics Goals Dashboard

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

Is there any OOB way to change the report header labels in Sitecore Experience Analytics Dashboard for Goals section reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

To edit the title of any of the xAnalytics reports you can go to the Sitecore desktop, select the Core database and navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/Conversions/Goals`. This is where your Goals reports live. Under the PageSettings item there are multiple report parameter items, select the one you want to change and edit the `Title` field.

Unsure which report it is that you want to change? Download and install the Visual Studio extension [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks), create a new connection to your site, find the `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/Conversions/Goals` item in the Sitecore Explorer, right click and select Design Layout. In here you'll see which reports have been added to the Goals page and you can use the `Data Source` field to find the GUID of your item.

Comment: I actually had gone through this content item in Core db. But I didn't find any option to rename the labels being shown in the report. We can change the metrics and other elements  but I'm not able to to the space where the report query is being built to change the label names.

Comment: In the master db, I've found 'Visit Goals' item (/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Report Queries/Visit Goals). But then here, we don't have any sql statement. The query field has GetVisitGoals''" as value and DataSource as "function"". But then I'm not able to get to this datasoure. I checked sql functions in db. But nothing with this name.